# how to validate matching values from Excel with UI, inside the for loop test and show the result in extent report

Tags: java, selenium, junit, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am using Selenium with JUnit and I need to verify a Reference number and Quantity from Excel sheet against UI values, from Step 8 onwards in given for loop.

Currently it is validated inside the method which I'm using in for loop we can check through sys logs, but I need the same validations in Extent Reports.

I am already using extent report below, but it shows all the test as passed even if logs are different, only because there is no assertion.

To Summarize:
How do I insert assertion to check values inside FOR LOOP and make them PASS and FAIL in Extent Report.

Test File Code:

```
public class TestCase extends AppTest {

    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        preparation = new Prep();
        application = new AppToTest();
        user = new Environment();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLAP_Creamix() throws Exception {
        try {
            launchMainApplication();

            Test_frMain Test_frMainPage = new Test_frMain(tool, test, user, application);

            HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> win = CreamixWindowsDataset.main();
            SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(win.keySet());
            ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("Test_Report.html");
            ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

            ExtentTest test1 = extent.createTest("Creamix test");

            for (String i : keys) {
                System.out.println("########### Test = " + win.get(i).get(0) + " ###########");
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.EnterTaille(win.get(i).get(1));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectCONFIGURATION(win.get(i).get(2));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectPLANVASQUE(win.get(i).get(3));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectCOULEUR(win.get(i).get(4));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectPOIGNEES(win.get(i).get(5));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectTYPE_DE_MEUBLE(win.get(i).get(6));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.SelectCHOISISSEZ(win.get(i).get(7));

                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCE(win.get(i).get(8));(FROM HERE Validation Starts)
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITY(win.get(i).get(9));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCETwo(win.get(i).get(10));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYTwo(win.get(i).get(11));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCEThree(win.get(i).get(12));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYThree(win.get(i).get(13));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCEFour(win.get(i).get(14));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYFour(win.get(i).get(15));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCEFive(win.get(i).get(16));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYFive(win.get(i).get(17));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCESix(win.get(i).get(18));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYSix(win.get(i).get(19));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCESeven(win.get(i).get(20));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyQUANTITYSeven(win.get(i).get(21));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyPanierPrice(win.get(i).get(22));
                Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyECO_PARTPrice(win.get(i).get(23));

                Lapeyre_frMainPage.ClickCREAMIXReinit();(Reset button to test next scenario)

                test1.pass("Scenario " + win.get(i).get(0) + " is passed");
                System.out.println("########### Test End ##############");
                extent.flush();

            }

            test.setResult("pass");
        } catch (AlreadyRunException e) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            verificationErrors.append(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }

    }

    @Override
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current code, I would suggest that you replace all the `.VerifyX()` methods to `.GetX()` methods and instead assert the two values in the script. For example,

```
Lapeyre_frMainPage.VerifyREFERENCE(win.get(i).get(8));
```

would be changed to

```
assertEquals("Verify REFERENCE 1", win.get(i).get(8), Lapeyre_frMainPage.GetREFERENCE());
```

`.GetREFERENCE()` would return the value from the UI instead of doing the verification.

---

For this to work, you need to change each of the `VerifyX()` methods to return the string from the UI. From your code in the comments, here's an example.

```
public void GetREFERENCE()
{
    return tool.searchUsingXPath("//tbody//tr[1]//td//div[2]").getText().trim();
}
```

Comment: While using .GetREFERENCE() I am getting following error "The method assertEquals(String, Object, Object) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, void)"

My get reference method looks like

Comment: public void GetREFERENCE_One() throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Verifying reference article");
  WebElement referenceOne = tool.searchUsingXPath("//tbody//tr[1]//td//div[2]");
  String Ref1 = referenceOne.getText().trim();
  System.out.println(Ref1);

 }

Comment: You have to change the `GetREFERENCE()` method to actually return the string from the UI that you want to compare. I've updated my answer with some example code based on the code in your comment.